# How can I use unordered_map<string::iterator, string>?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I have a function with the following signature:

```
void findDotStars(unordered_map<string::iterator, string>& fp, string& p)
```

I get [C2280](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(C2280)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170) compiler's error. I need to store pointers to parts of string. I think that I need to convert iterator to pointer, but to which pointer?

Comment: There's not enough info here to help.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Probably you can't use iterator as a key. Even more, it makes nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The type `std::string::iterator` is implementation defined, so there might or might not be a specialisation of `std::hash` for it. If there isn't, then you need to write one. If there is, then you must not write one.

There definitely will be a specialisation for `std::string::pointer`, so you could use that instead, although you will have to be careful about iterator's that equal the string's `end()`.